# Как удалить через jquery определенные теги, не нарушая информацию и остальные теги в них

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Здравствуйте, есть структура

```
<div>

    <img src="" alt="">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <img src="" alt="">

</div>
```

В нее могут вноситься лишние `<div>` и `<p>`, обертывая изображения,  как можно их находить и убирать, не убирая изображения в них

Comment: [jquery.unwrap](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть метод .detach(), он удаляет элемент и сохраняет его в переменную и можно с помощью .append() или .prepend() можно добавить во внутрь обертки.
Например:

```
переменная=$(селектор).detach() //удаляем и сохраняем в переменную
$(селектор).append(переменная) // добавляем последним к родительскому элементу
$(селектор).prepend(переменная) // добавляем первым к родительскому элементу
```

Answer (score 0):

Простой вариант

```
<div id="bb">

    <img src="" alt="">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <p><img src="" alt=""></p>
    <div><img src="" alt=""></div>
    <img src="" alt="">

</div>

<script>
    var $bb = $('#bb');
    $bb.html($bb.find('img'));
</script>
```